# Using Atomminer AM01's fpga for purposes other than mining

Tags: fpga, vhdl, hacking

I was thinking about Using Atomminer AM01's fpga for purposes other than mining, maybe using vhdl or verilog, I wanted to ascend if it is possible?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/atomminer/am01 looks to contain the schematic for an AM01, and there is also a constraints file. There is no FPGA configuration flash for the XC7A200T-1FBG484I FPGA, and the CYUSB3014-BZXC appears to be used to download the FPGA bitstream over USB from a connected USB host. I.e. after power-up you would need to download a bitstream over USB.

There also appears to be an unpopulated header on the PCB to support a JTAG connection to the FPGA, which would be an alternative means to download a bitstream and also support debugging.

I think the above is sufficient information to allow the AM01 to be repurposed as a general purpose XC7A200T FPGA with a USB connection to a PC for communication.

There is the following on the github project [README.md](https://github.com/atomminer/am01/blob/master/README.md):

> **WARNING** any use of custom unsigned bitstreams will void your warranty and might render devices unusable.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably possible, if it has JTAG you can upload any code you want.

That said one big strength of FPGAs is IO, and there's none on this board. Everything has to go through USB. That's fine for mining or using the FPGA to perform calculations on data provided by the USB host, but you can't interface it to anything else.

So while you most likely can upload your code on this board, whether it will be a suitable board or not really depends on what you intend to do with it.

If you want to learn FPGAs I'd recommend a board with a lot more IO so you can do VGA or DVI/HDMI/DP outputs, it's a lot more fun.

Comment: Thanks. And thanks for the Recommendation, I will get an altera or cheap xilinxs dev Board and a cheap siipeed fpga Board just because its very cheap and I can afford to experiment with it without being scared of breaking it. I was asking about the atomminer because I saw an offer for 100$ and the fpga is pretty impressive for the price

Comment: I guess the reason it's cheap second hand is... due to lack of IO, only thing you can do with it is stuff similar to mining, offloading calculations from the CPU to the FPGA...